# Viewing localhost website/webapplication from Android mobile device

Tags: asp.net, mobile, windows-8, localhost, vs-web-site-project

I have a ASP.Net website and webApplication running correctly on my windows Machine-local host.
I need to test the website on mobile device to check the aesthetics and UI.

My mobile device is connected to a Router via Wifi to which my computer is hardwired connected.

I have tried the following, but in vain:

Option I:1) Created an Inbound Rule (Control Panel > System and Security > Firewall > Advanced settings) for TCP and UDP for Port No:1234

2) Tried accessing my website from mobile device by navigating to : http://192.168.X.X:12345/    (But this option did not work)

Option II: 1) Tried changing the 'applicationhost.config' file from the /IISExpress/config/ folder.

2) Added the following two line:

```
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:192.168.X.X" />

    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":12345:MyComputerName"/>
```

(But this also did not help)

Option III: I am using the VS2013, in the properties section of the Webapplication under Tab "Web", I tried clicking the "Create Virtual Directory" button but it does not allow me to create.
Also I tried selecting the IIS Express and Local IIS  (but this did'nt help either.)

Could you correct any of the above steps which I could have done wrong

OR provide me a working technique to test the ASP website on a Mobile device

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment it but i do not have the reputation to comment.
Anyways, If it is just the UI you are after then why not use the chrome dev tools? Press f12 then click toggle device mode. You will still need to test on the actual device though but for a quick development that is what i do.